# C# Error when adding existing user to existing group

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I have two sites, each has its own Scheduler with enough rights to do their job.  We created an application to allow them to quickly add a user to AD with every thing the user will need.  The problem is that sometimes, a student will transfer from one site to the other temporarily.  While at the new site, they will need access to all their original stuff, plus access to the new sites stuff as well.

I had a request to add a button that will quickly allow them to add the other sites groups and not remove the original sites groups.

The error I am getting is:

```
Error adding User to Group.
System.Directory.Services.AccountManagement.NoMatchingPrincipalException:
No principal matching the specified paramenters was found
    at 
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.principalCollection.add(principalContext context, identitytype itedentity type, string identitiyvalue)
at AddStudentUser.Form2.AddUserToGroup_fm2(string userID, string groupName, string siteName) identitiyvalue
c:\projects\AddStudentUser\AddStudentUser\Form2.cs:line 113
```

Here is the code I am calling:

```
    private void btnUpdateExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //userUPN will equal Loginname@domain.com
        string userUPN = this.tbUserLoginName.Text.Trim().ToString() + Form1.Globs.strUPN;
        if (this.cbSite1.Checked == true & this.cbSite1.Enabled==true)
        {
            AddUserToGroup_fm2(userUPN, "Site1", Form1.Globs.strSUUADC);
            AddUserToGroup_fm2(userUPN, "Crew_Site1", Form1.Globs.strSite1ADC);
            AddUserToGroup_fm2(userUPN, "WWW-Site1", Form1.Globs.strSite1ADC);
            MessageBox.Show("User has been added to the Site1 Groups.");
        }
        if (this.cbSite2.Checked == true & this.cbSite2.Enabled == true)
        {
            AddUserToGroup_fm2(userUPN, "Site2", Form1.Globs.strWRIADC);
            AddUserToGroup_fm2(userUPN, "Crew_Site2", Form1.Globs.strSite2ADC);
            AddUserToGroup_fm2(userUPN, "WWW-Site2", Form1.Globs.strSite2ADC);
            MessageBox.Show("User has been added to the Site2 Groups.");
        }
        this.Close();
    }
    public void AddUserToGroup_fm2(string userId, string groupName, string siteName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, siteName))
            {
                GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
                group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);

                group.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error adding User to Group. " + E);

        }
    }
```

The weird thing is that if I add a new user, the same code on a different form works without issue.  I initially tried calling that code but was getting the same error as I am getting now. I wanted to separate the code so that I could make changes to it without affecting the original function, since it works fine when adding a new user to existing groups.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Error in `group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);`, why ?

Answer (score 0):

**IdentityType.SamAccountName**

```
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, siteName))
        {
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
            group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userId);

            group.Save();
        }
```